# Lock table before inserting in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I have the following scenario:

- A user can create orders having a given amount (e.g.: 500$)
- There is a limit for the total orders' amount that can be added for a single day (e.g.: max 2000$/day)

At the moment, when creating a new order, this requirement is implemented as follows:

```
var newOrder = /* logic for creating the new order */;

var orders = _ordersRepository.GetAllBy(userId, date); // get the orders from the db
var totalAmount = orders.Sum(o => o.Amount); 
if(totalAmount < MaximumAmount) {
  newOrder.IsApproved = true;
}
else {
  newOrder.IsApproved = false;
}

_ordersRepository.Add(newOrder);
_ordersRepository.SaveChanges(); // insert into the db
```

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't handle concurrent insertions properly in scenarios like:

- Maximum orders limit: 2000$
- In a single second, a user sends 10 requests for creating 10 new orders of 500$ each

The requests are handled concurrently and because of the short timeframe, the currently implemented check is executed before the new orders are saved in the database and therefore allows creating all of them. In the end, the user ends exceeding the maximum limit.

How could I solve this issue, ideally without having to call `SaveChanges` multiple times? I'm using Entity Framework Core 5 and SQL Server.

Comment: Carry out your update using a stored procedure, serialise your stored procedure so only one instance can run at a time, and carry out the check there.

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without stored procedures or doing stuff directly in SQL? I would like to have such checks in c# in order to have all the data access and business logic in a single place.

Comment: You would have to ensure that you serialise your requests so that only one is ever processed at a time. Maybe by funnelling all requests via a singleton (tricky if using a website processed by multiple worker threads) or queue (not real time). I appreciate the desire to keep all business logic in code, but sometime when it related to data integrity its a lot easier, and accurate to do it in the database. In fact you might even want to consider a trigger as a last line of defence to ensure that anyone doing a manual insert into the database also respects the rules.

Comment: Try wrapping to whole procedure (including reads) into short explicit serializable transaction. You'll need access to the `DbContext` and code like `using var transction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);`. Don't forget to call `Commit()` after successfull `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions from the comments!

I've tried using transactions with the `IsolationLevel` set to `Serializable`, but then I've realized this would lock too many tables (the example from the question is a dummy one, the actual implementation is more complex).

I agree that sometimes it might be easier to have this kind of logic in the database, but adding a stored procedure for this will kind of break the current consistency and most probably leave the door open for other stored procedures. I'm not saying stored procedures are bad, just that in my current situation, even if it is a bit harder/more complex to achieve this without them, I believe it's worth it for consistency reasons.

### The solution I've ended with

I've ended splitting the flow in 2 steps as follows:

```
// step 1
var newOrder = /* logic for creating the new order */;
_ordersRepository.Add(newOrder);
_ordersRepository.SaveChanges(); // insert into the db

// step 2
var orders = _ordersRepository.GetAllBy(userId, date); // get the orders from the db
var totalAmount = orders.Sum(o => o.Amount); 
if(totalAmount < MaximumAmount) {
  newOrder.IsApproved = true;
}
_ordersRepository.Update(newOrder); 
_ordersRepository.SaveChanges(); // update the new order
```

- Step 1 just creates the new order and inserts it into the database, the `IsApproved` flag being left to the default which is `false`.
- Step 2 performs the daily limit validation and if the check passes, the `IsApproved` flag to `true`.

I know it's not an actual solution, but a workaround. Locking a table might have a too big performance impact, especially if the given table is used by multiple app features. With this solution, even if there was an issue in the Step 2, the order will be left with `IsApproved=false` so it won't have any impact and the user can either try again later, or somebody from support can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use lock statement to prevent user parallel requests.

https://github.com/Darkseal/LockProvider

```
    public static async Task CreateOrder(currentUserId)
    {
        // lock for currentUserId only
        await LockProvider.WaitAsync(currentUserId);
    
        try
        {
             var newOrder = /* logic for creating the new order */;

             var orders = _ordersRepository.GetAllBy(userId, date); // get the orders from the db
             var totalAmount = orders.Sum(o => o.Amount); 
             if(totalAmount < MaximumAmount) {
                 newOrder.IsApproved = true;
             }
             else {
                 newOrder.IsApproved = false;
             }

             _ordersRepository.Add(newOrder);
             _ordersRepository.SaveChanges(); // insert into the db
        }
        finally
        {
            // release the lock
            LockProvider.Release(currentUserId);
        }
    }
```